# C# "Conversion failed when converting date/time from character string" But query works well when run on server

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

I am incorporating a SQL Server query in C# and using a RDLC report to show query results. My query produces the correct result when run on SQL Server, but I get an error

> Conversion failed  when converting date/time from character string

when using it from C# code. I could not figure out why got this error. Please help me

C# code:

```
DateTime Date =DateTime.Parse(d2.Value.Date.ToString());
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
MessageBox.Show(Date.ToString(format));             
this.soldItemsDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.Daily_Sales_Report.SoldItemsDetails, Date.ToString(format));
```

The error occurs on the last line of this code.

Date stored in database in format '`yyyy-MM-dd`' and the above code produces  date format as required as confirmed by the following code:

```
MessageBox.Show(Date.ToString(format));
```

SQL Server query:

```
SELECT 
    b.CompanyID, b.Category, a.ModelNo, a.ProductCode, a.Qty
FROM    
    (SELECT 
         s.DateSold, p.ProductID, p.ModelNo, p.ProductCode, 
         SUM(sipl.SubTotal) AS Qty
     FROM 
         SalesInvoiceProductsList AS sipl 
     INNER JOIN 
         SalesInvoice AS s ON sipl.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
     INNER JOIN 
         Product AS p ON sipl.ProductID = p.ProductID
     GROUP BY 
         p.ModelNo, p.ProductCode, p.ProductID, s.DateSold) AS a 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         p.ProductID, p.CompanyID, cat.Category
     FROM 
         Product AS p 
     INNER JOIN 
         Category AS cat ON p.CatID = cat.CatID 
     INNER JOIN 
         Company AS c ON p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
WHERE  
    (a.DateSold = @Date)
ORDER BY 
    b.CompanyID
```

If I use simple query which also takes `date` input instead of this complex query then got NO error. However his complex query works fine on SQL Server.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` is **not** language/datatype unambiguous. Depending on your language setting (and if you are using the datatype `datetime`) the date `2019-03-01` could be interpreted as 01 March 2019 or 03 January 2019. That becomes a problem, therefore, with a date like `2019-03-16`, as there aren't 16 months in a year. Use the ISO format `yyyyMMdd` to ensure that the date will **always** be interpreted correctly.

Comment: But if use simple query which uses the same date format gives no error and produces correct result

Comment: If dates are stored as `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2(n)` in SQL Server, they **have NO format** - those are **binary** datatypes. They only get a format when being **displayed** to the user

Comment: What is the database datatype of `DateSold`?

Comment: Database datatype of DateSold is "Date"

Comment: Example of the behaviour: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ebfa89df29607bfe984039582c2238e). Notice that the first line has 2 different dates, and in the second, one fails to be converted.

Comment: But, @shakeel, from your code, it looks like `@Date` is a `datetime`. Give the format `yyyyMMdd` a try; I suspect it will work. :)

Comment: i changed the @Date data type from date to datetime but still got the same error

Comment: `datetime` isn't going to help the problem here.

Comment: I modify the above code i.e string format = "yyyyMMdd"  but still got same error

Comment: You really, really don't want to be converting your date to a string at all. The database type is a date/datetime, your C# type is a DateTime, pass it through as a DateTime parameterised and let whatever DB adapter you're using convert it directly in the correct way. Putting dates in strings for anything other than a human reading them leads to fragile, non-portable code that breaks in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by changing nothing except the query. Both queries executes well on server but the integration of first query issue the error under discussion but the following query does not issue any error, although the date format is same in both queries. I could not understand the reason. Can anybody explain why?

```
SELECT com.CompanyID AS company, c.Category, p.ModelNo AS Model, (sipl.SubTotal) AS Qty
FROM    SalesInvoiceProductsList AS sipl 
        INNER JOIN SalesInvoice AS s ON sipl.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
        INNER JOIN Product AS p ON sipl.ProductID = p.ProductID 
        INNER JOIN Company AS com ON p.CompanyID = com.CompanyID 
        INNER JOIN Category AS c ON p.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE  (s.DateSold = @Date)
GROUP BY com.CompanyID, c.Category, p.ModelNo,sipl.SubTotal
```

Comment: You need to learn something important: For dates that are stored properly in a date data type, format is irrelevant. It appears from your comments that the date in the database is stored in the correct datatype, and as long as the variable in your code is also of type date then you should never go and format the date as a string. It's not a string it's a date, and dates are stored inherently correctly without any format. Your statement _Date stored in database in format 'yyyy-MM-dd'_ is incorrect. It is not stored in any format, and you should not be formatting it as anything.

Comment: I don't know how this new query works because I don't know how you are populating `@date` in it. But you should definitely not be doing `string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";` at all.